# How to define a functor fixpoint?

Tags: functor, agda

In Haskell i can define an endofunctor fixpoint so:

```
data Fix f = Fix (f (Fix f))
```

But in Agda can't:

```
data Fix (F : Id (Set → Set)) : Set where
    fix : (unId F) (Fix F) → Fix F
```

as it says "Fix is not strictly positive, because it occurs in an argument to a bound variable in the type of the constructor fix in the definition of Fix."

I tried using `Coinduction.∞` from the stdlib, in vain:

```
data Fix (F : Set → Set) : Set where
    fix : ∞ (F (Fix F)) → Fix F
```

or

```
data Fix (F : Set → Set) : Set where
    fix : F (∞ (Fix F)) → Fix F
```

neither works.

I found [this doc](http://ecee.colorado.edu/~siek/plpv07-schwaab.pdf) which defines polynomial functors `Functor` and a function `[_] : Functor → Set → Set` which works:

```
data Functor : Set₁ where
    Id : Functor
    Const : Set → Functor
    _⊕_ : Functor → Functor → Functor
    _⊗_ : Functor → Functor → Functor

[_] : Functor → Set → Set
[ Id ] B = B
[ Const C ] _ = C
[ F ⊕ G ] B = [ F ] B ⊎ [ G ] B
[ F ⊗ G ] B = [ F ] B × [ G ] B

data Fix (F : Functor) : Set where
    fix : [ F ] (Fix F) → Fix F
```

but i'm not sure why that would and this wouldn't, as both have `Fix` as an argument to the bound variable `F`.

Can one define a general endofunctor fixpoint in Agda, and if so, how?

EDIT: This was marked as a possible duplicate of [14699334](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699334/recursion-schemes-in-agda), but the only answer there links to an (the?) Agda tutorial which includes fixpoints of a specific polynomial functor type; i want to know whether one can define this more generally. In particular, i want to define fixpoints of types which may be structurally equal but are nominally inequal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursion Schemes in Agda](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699334/recursion-schemes-in-agda)

Comment: Are you sure that the Haskell data Fix is not just the Y-combinator? Could the Agda data Fix also be defined as a Y-combinator? I don't know Agda. It seems all functions are endo because they operate on themselves determined by type. Do you want a total function to handle any type? I just configure my functions to any type within reason. You can calculate with ['a'..'z'] but the calculation is mostly repetitious or boring unless maybe something in group theory.  I know this is old and you've moved on but there were no comments even.